# Compiling with -fPIC and Swig error

Tags: c++, swig

I'm trying to add a Swig interface on top of some already existing c++ code and I'm coming up with some errors with the `-fPIC` flag.

If I compile the already existing code without `-fPIC` and then create my Swig module using:

```
swig -python -c++ pyinterface.i
gcc -fPIC $(CFLAGS)-I $(PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR) -c pyinterface_wrap.cxx
g++ -shared -o _pyinterface.so pyinterface_wrap.o -I $(PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR) -L $(PYTHON_LIB_DIR) $(LPATH) $(LFLAGS) $(IPATH) $(LIBS)
```

Then I get a

```
warning: creating a DT_TEXTREL in object
```

However the module does seem to load and work in Python.

If I compile the already existing code with `-fPIC` and then do the same to create my module, when I try and import it into python:

```
import pyinterface
```

Then I get the error

```
ImportError: ./_pyinterface.so: undefined symbol: _Z7InitErfPA20_d
```

I can't tell why this would be. However, in the compliation of the base c++ files that I am trying to wrap, they do link to some standard libraries such as `-llapack`.

Could it be that I need to recompile these base libraries, like lapack, with `-fPIC`. That seems insane.

EDIT:

Actually sorry, I didn't realise, but with the -fPIC flag on I'm getting an error during compile:

```
g++: Internal error: Killed (program cc1plus)
```

Please submit a full bug report.
See http://bugs.gentoo.org/ for instructions.

I'll update this question if I figure out whats going on, but it seems like it might be unrelated to anything that the question actually raises.

Comment: What architecture and OS are you using? My current best guess is that your _pyinterface module isn't actually linked against your C++ library, or there's a name mangling problem, i.e. you call C code from C++ but are missing `extern "C"` with the declarations.

Comment: 32 bit, linux. The base c++ code does call some C code (from lapack for instance) but that all works usually. You could be right about the linking, but then wouldn't both these methods fail?

Comment: Can you make a minimal (e.g. 10 lines, single trivial inlined function) example that illustrates this? I'd have a play with it on my system and figure out what's going on, but I can't do more than guess from this right now.

Comment: You correctly list `g++` as the linker driver, but `gcc` as the compiler driver. But you should always compile C++ with `g++` driver too. That might be your problem.

Comment: The warning is because you are linking object file compiled without `-fPIC`. Maybe some of libraries you link is static and compiled without `-fPIC`.

Comment: Flexo: I will have a go at doing this. I'll update the question if I manage to get something workable.

Comment: Jan - changing both to g++ doesn't make a difference. And yes, I get the warning when I compile with -fPIC, that is why I added the flag. Unfortunately adding the flag seems to break it somehow.

Comment: You say it's insane that the base libraries need to be compiled with -fPIC, but sadly it's true. Welcome to the love/hate world of Python :)

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong regarding this reply.

Regarding the warning: creating a DT_TEXTREL in object

Even I was getting the same warning.

In my Makefile; I had done something like this

SRC= ../../some_folder/file.c 1.c 2.c

OBJS= $(SRC:.c=.o)

and while making the shared object, i was using this $(OBJS); whereas the "file.o" would be available at that location.

Make sure the object files that you are trying to access are available at that location.

My warning message vanished when i made the following changes

OBJS=file.o 1.o 2.o

Comment: Thanks for your input, but sorry this was too long ago for me to remember what this is all about. So I have no idea if your problem is the same as that I was experiencing.